# How would you verify the following trig identity $\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}=\frac{\sec(x)}{\sec(x)+\cos(x)}$

Tags: trigonometry

How to verify the following trig identity.

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}=\frac{\sec(x)}{\sec(x)+\cos(x)}$$

I started with the right side and multiplied the numerator and denominator by $\sec(x)-\cos(x)$

then I got

$$\frac{\sec^2(x)-1}{\sec^2(x)-\cos^2(x)}=\frac{\tan^2(x)}{\sec^2(x)-\cos^2(x)}$$

but now I am stuck.

Comment: The identity is false: set $x=0$ and the left hand side is $0$, but the right hand side is $1/2$.

Comment: Your identity isn't an identity.  So pick a value of x and show that it is not true.

Comment: Oh I guess my book must have a typo or something fo sure.

Comment: If your identity was true it would imply that $\sin x = \sec x$ for all real $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a typo, either in your question or in your book. Is it possible it was meant to be
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}=\frac{\sec(x)}{\sec(x)+\csc(x)}$$
instead (note "$\csc$" instead of "$\cos$")?

If so, you can get this by just dividing each term on the left by $\sin x \cos x$.

Comment: Good spot deserves a +1

Answer (score 5):

If you could cross multiply this, you will get:

$sin(x)(sec(x)+cos(x))=sec(x)(sin(x)+cos(x))$

$\Rightarrow sin(x)(\frac{1}{cos(x)}+cos(x))=\frac{1}{cos(x)}(sin(x)+cos(x))$

$\Rightarrow \frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}+sin(x)cos(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}+\frac{cos(x)}{cos(x)}$

$\Rightarrow sin(x)cos(x)=1$

$\Rightarrow 2sin(x)cos(x)=sin(2x)=2$

There's no such $x$ such that it holds. So it is not a valid identity.

Comment: but $\sin x \cos x \ne 1$ for any x.  After all, that would imply that $\sin 2x = 2$

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that the right hand side is $(1+\cos^2x)^{-1}$; so the equality holds if and only if
$$
\sin x(1+\cos^2x)=\sin x+\cos x
$$
that is
$$
\sin x\cos^2x-\cos x=0
$$
Since $\cos x\ne0$ as you need to use the secant, it only remains $\sin x\cos x=1$, which has no solution.

So the equality holds for *no* value of $x$.

On the other hand
$$
\frac{\sec x}{\sec x+\csc x}=
\frac{\dfrac{1}{\cos x}}{\dfrac{1}{\cos x}+\dfrac{1}{\sin x}}=
\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}
$$
So the correct identity is
$$
\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}=\frac{\sec x}{\sec x+\csc x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If both sides are  defined (i.e. $\;x\neq \dfrac\pi2, \dfrac{3\pi}4\mod\pi$)
\begin{align*}\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}&=\frac{\sec x}{\sec x+\cos x}\iff \sin x(\sec x+\cos x)=(\sin x+\cos x)\sec x\\
&\iff \sin x \cos x=\sec x\cos x\iff\sin x =\sec x\iff\frac12\sin2x=1,\\
\end{align*}
which  has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an identity. Because,when we putting the value of both sides of the identity we get two different value. Left hand value is 0.Right hand value is (1÷2).